# Connecting to mysql container from host

Tags: mysql, docker, containers

I have installed docker on my mac. I have MySQL container which is running on my local machine (MAC).

Docker ps command is giving me below output -

```
CONTAINER ID   IMAGE          COMMAND                   CREATED         STATUS                 PORTS                     NAMES

b5c50b2d334a   test_mysql2    "docker-entrypoint.s…"    2 hours ago     Up 2 hours (healthy)   0.0.0.0:32783->3306/tcp   test_mysql2_1
```

I know username and password to the mysql which would be setup up in the container.

I want to connect to mysql and run some queries But I am not able to figure out how to connect to it. Any help will be appreciated.

Comment: Have you tried `docker exec -ti b5c50b2d334a bash` to access via cli? There are many ways to connect it.

Comment: Yeah, i was able to login to container via this. But didnt know how to connect to mysql further.

Answer (score 0):

Do you want to Connect to MySQL through Docker if yes; Kindly follow this step by step procedure that I am using.

**Step 1** : Pull MySql image from docker hub. The following command will pull the latest mysql image.

```
cli> docker pull mysql
```

**Step 2**: Run a container from this image. ‘-name’ gives a name to the container. ‘ -e’ specifies run time variables you need to set. Set the password for the MySQL root user using ‘MYSQL_ROOT_PASSWORD’. ‘-d’ tells the docker to run the container in background.

```
cli> docker run --name=testsql -e MYSQL_ROOT_PASSWORD=rukshani -d mysql
```

This will output a container id; which means that the container is running in the background properly.

**Step 3**: Then check the status of the container by issuing, ‘docker ps’ command

```
cli> docker ps
```

Now you should be able to see that MySQL is running on port 3306.

**Step 4**: To checkout the logs of the running container use the following command

```
cli > docker logs testsql
```

**Step 5**: Find the IP of the container using following. Check out the “IPAddress” from the output, this will tell you the IP address.

```
cli> docker inspect testsql
```

Now you should be able to connect to MySQL using tIPs ip address on port 3306.

Base on what I understand from your question, this is what you need. (I hope so)

(This is not my own documentation, I only like to document everything most especially those procedure that I cannot put in my head, so that if ever the same thing happen or I need same procedure in the future, I will not waste my time to research again, but instead I will open my notes and run the commands.)

Answer (score 0):

As you can see in the output of `docker ps`, the port `32783` (local machine) is mapped to the port `3306` inside the docker container. If you are using a MySQL Client (e.g. MySQL Workbench) you should be able to connect using ip `localhost` and port `32783`. If not, you should go with `docker exec` and then open a interactive mysql shell inside the container (As mulg0r commented).